# Add name and number from data file to each icon

Tags: captions, datatool

Thank you for this solution of Jasper Habicht - in related topic:
[Simplify code for repeating same image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625240/simplify-code-for-repeating-same-image/625263#625263)

How can I add No and Name (from my data.tex file) under each image (and maybe use the `datatool` package)?

Current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
 \usepackage{datatool}
 
\newcounter{repeatcount}
\newcommand{\repeatthis}[3][]{%
    \setcounter{repeatcount}{0}%
    \loop%
    {#3}%
    \stepcounter{repeatcount}%
    \ifnum\value{repeatcount}<#2%
    {#1}%
    \repeat%
}
%\DTLsetseparator{|}
%\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
%\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{data}{data.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\repeatthis[\quad]{15}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

My TeX file data.tex:

```
No|Name

1|AAA

2|BCA

3|DXY
```

[image]

Comment: You want to insert No. and Name not only to the first line, I guess?

Comment: Thanks. i need insert No, Name under all images.

Comment: Please consider to state as precisely as possible what you really want to get in the end: Do you wish to put images with captions based on *different* entries from a database, or do you want to repeat *the same* images with captions multiple times? I'm a little confused as to what your goal is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that the solution from my other answer is of much use here, since you don't want to repeat the very same thing, but you want to iterate over data that comes from a database.

Instead, you probably want to make use of the functions that come with the `datatool` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents}{data.tex}
No|Name
1|AAA
2|BCA
3|DXY
\end{filecontents}
 
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{data}{data.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\DTLforeach{data}{\dataNo=No,\dataName=Name}{%
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} \\
    \dataNo, \dataName
\end{minipage}\quad%
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To get more pictures with numbers and names, just add more lines to the file `data.tex`. For every line in this file, there will be another image with caption added to the page.

---

In case you would like to repeat these three lines again and again, you could actually combine the `datatool` approach with the macro of my other answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcounter{repeatcount}
\newcommand{\repeatthis}[3][]{%
    \setcounter{repeatcount}{0}%
    \loop%
    {#3}%
    \stepcounter{repeatcount}%
    \ifnum\value{repeatcount}<#2%
    {#1}%
    \repeat%
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.tex}
No|Name
1|AAA
2|BCA
3|DXY
\end{filecontents}
 
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{data}{data.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\repeatthis{5}{%
\DTLforeach{data}{\dataNo=No,\dataName=Name}{%
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} \\
    \dataNo, \dataName
\end{minipage}\quad%
}%
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: beauftiful output. But i need (number and name) under all images, not only 3 first images. Please help. thank you

Comment: Do you want to repeat these three numbers and names again in the next lines? Then, we could maybe combine this solution with the other ... Otherwise, you can just add more lines to the document that contains the data.